# Baking several materials

Tags: texture-baking

So basically I'm really new to blender, and I made this

[image: selected object]

And now I'm trying to make a texture image so that I can use it in Roblox, as I am a roblox modeller.
How do I go about doing this? I'm completely new so please break it down as simple as possible

Comment: I don't think many Blenderers know what Roblox is. What are you using the textures for?

Comment: I want to export the textures so I can apply them on the object in the game

Comment: Export? Go to the image editor, load the texture, press ALT S, save the file.